# ReactJS - large video files make computer to freeze after npm start

Tags: reactjs, video, npm, webpack, mp4

I've got my small react web app that runs with no problems while having five low quality videos.
But once I add multiple large high quality video files and I start the app, my laptop freezes and I need to manually shut it down.

```
//outside the component class 
function importAll(r){
  let images = {};
  r.keys().forEach((item) => { images[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
  return images;
}

componentDidMount() { 
const videos = importAll(require.context('./videos', false, /\.mp4$/));
 window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll); 
}
```

My videos folder is on my src folder, Any advice?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: What's the purpose of importing such heavy assets?

Comment: so i could later show a video by a user clicking on that video image

Comment: Which webpack loader do you use for videos?